# Choosing the button in different rows in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

I have a table with "Foo" links, in the beggining it will be always 20.
After I click the link I might have a button.

I would like to write a programme, which covers both functionalities:

Click the first "Foo" link and:

1. if button is visible click it, go back, and click again the first "Foo link". The old one disappeared after clicking, but on the bottom a new one will be added,
2. if the button is not visible, go back and choose the "Foo" link in next row (add to counter an offset).

I tried with the following code:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.linkText("Never"));
    System.out.println(driver.findElements(By.linkText("Foo")).size());
        int nextRow=0;
        int uncleanedSubmissions = 0;
        int cleanedSubmissions = 0;
        System.out.println(nextRow);
        do {
            elements.get(nextRow).click();
            Helper.sleep(3000, driver);
            if (driver.findElement(By.className("button")).isDisplayed()) {                 
                driver.findElement(By.className("button")).click();
                driver.get(baseUrl);
                cleanedSubmissions++;
                System.out.println(nextRow);
            } else if (!(driver.findElement(By.className("button").isDisplayed())) {
                uncleanedSubmissions++;
                nextRow++;
                System.out.println(uncleanedSubmissions + ". submission has not been cleaned");
                driver.get(baseUrl);
            }
        } while (nextRow < 20);
```

It's simplified to prevent long classes names and wait lines, which are not important here.

When I execute this code, I get an error: `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0`

In my opinion because I try to click the "Foo" link incorrectly (`elements.get(nextRow).click();` can't use the nextRow in this way).

How it should be implemented?

**The HTML code:**

```
    <table class="taglib-search-iterator" data-searchcontainerid="_151_workflowInstancesSearchContainer">
<tbody>
<tr class="portlet-section-header results-header">
<tr class="lfr-template portlet-section-body results-row">
<tr class="portlet-section-body results-row">
<tr class="portlet-section-alternate results-row alt">
<tr class="portlet-section-body results-row">
<tr class="portlet-section-alternate results-row alt">
       <td id="col-end-date_row-5" class="align-left">
            <a href="FooLink">Foo</a>
      </td>
</tr>
<tr class="portlet-section-body results-row">
<tr class="portlet-section-alternate results-row alt">
<tr class="portlet-section-body results-row">
<tr class="portlet-section-alternate results-row alt">
       <td id="col-end-date_row-9" class="align-left">
            <a href="FooLink">Foo</a>
      </td>
</tr>
<tr class="portlet-section-body results-row">
<tr class="portlet-section-alternate results-row alt">
<tr class="portlet-section-body results-row">
<tr class="portlet-section-alternate results-row alt">
<tr class="portlet-section-body results-row">
<tr class="portlet-section-alternate results-row alt">
<tr class="portlet-section-body results-row">
<tr class="portlet-section-alternate results-row alt">
<tr class="portlet-section-body results-row">
<tr class="portlet-section-alternate results-row alt">
<tr class="portlet-section-body results-row">
<tr class="portlet-section-alternate results-row alt last">
</tbody>
</table>
```

Other `tr` are exactly the same - one is expanded for the example.

And the example of the page with the button is just (excluding other css issues, no iframe):

```
<a id="button" class="taglib-icon" href="Linkhere">
```

But this page does not contain anything else important.

**EDIT 2:**
I have changed my code to following as above - on the first run there is an error `StaleElementReferenceException: The element reference is stale.` which points to `elements.get(nextRow).click();` (got the `1. submission has not been cleaned` log) - the first run is the second case
I'll keep trying to solve it

Comment: Where is html code?

Comment: could you provide url or html code

Comment: Probably your code `driver.findElements(By.linkText("Foo"))` is not returning any record. That's why it says the size of your list is zero. Maybe you should review your HTML to find the elements you want.

Comment: added the HTML. I was also wondering if I can use the `td id`, which are incrementing like in `col-end-date_row-9`

Comment: @Tom but `int Number = driver.findElements(By.linkText("Foo")).size(); System.out.println(Number);` returns value 20

Comment: @Michal, where does your stacktrace `IndexOutOfBoundsException ` point to for that exception then? Is your code complete? This is the only list you have on it. Can you debug the code to find it?

Comment: add `List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.linkText("Foo"))`; line just after `do {` line.

Comment: @Tom, this is not the full code, I put only essential part - other methods like login in, checking other functions are not important to this part. This is the only list on the page there, other part of code is css containing pictures, other links etc etc
The error log shows to the `elements.get(nextRow).click();`

Comment: Edited my code as above

Comment: Found an issue, edited code I needed to add one more line as @kushalツ suggested, now it's working, thank you both! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your list size is `20`

`int Number = driver.findElements(By.linkText("Foo")).size();`

You should change the code of your while condition to

`while (nextRow<20);`

instead

`while (nextRow<=20);`